# Get the text or title from a clicked link in QWebEnginePage

Tags: python, hyperlink, click, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

So, the question is on using `QWebEngineView` or `QWebEnginePage`, or something like that. I have a link which looks like  `<a href="/salt">Salt</a>`. I have already managed to intercept clicking on this link and force `QWebEngineView` to do nothing with it because all that I need is to print the text of this url ("Salt") in the python console instead of opening it. The problem is that I haven't any idea how to implement it. There was `linkHovered()` signal in PyQt4 which returns the title, text and url of the link when the mouse hovers over it. In PyQt5 it returns only the url. Any ideas?

Some code:

```
class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    link_clicked = pyqtSignal(str)
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url, nav_type, is_frame):
        if nav_type == 0:
            self.link_clicked.emit(str(url))
            return False
        else:
            return True

self.page.link_clicked.connect(self.LEchange)

def LEchange(self,url):
    print(url)
```

It prints:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('file:///C:/salt')
```

but if the link looks like `<a href="/salt">Salt</a>` I need to get "Salt".

Comment: <a href="/salt"> Salt </a> is just an example, links actually looks like <a href="/Caterpillar"> Катерпиллар </a> or <a href="/gos"> Государство </a>(words aren't equal)

Comment: None of this is possible with `QWebEngine`. Everything happens aynchronously, and there is no direct access to the page elements at all. The only way you can interact with the html/dom is via javascript - but the web-page itself cannot tell you which element was clicked, so that is not much help. One thing you have to understand about `QWebEngine` is that it is not a drop-in replacement for `QWebKit`. There are many things that have not been implemented yet, and some that probably never will be.

Comment: But if I will use PyQt4 I will be able to do this via linkHovered, won’t I?

Comment: Yes, but PyQt4 only has webkit, not webengine. With webengine, the only way to get information about a clicked html/dom element is by using javascript.

Comment: I've understand, thx. JS is not my strong side. But migration from PyQt5 to PyQt4 doesn't look like a very hard task since I've used only few functions which according to Qt documentation differ only in name and type of returned values. Actually, i'm going to change `QWebEngineView` to `QWebView` (and ~Page to QWebPage). Hope it will work.